# PyQt Import Error

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a very simple PyQt program

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

widget = QWidget()
widget.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When I double click to run the program, it runs successfully.
But when I run it in command line: python test.py, I got the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from PyQt4.QtGui import *
ImportError: No module named PyQt4.QtGui
```

Comment: You're probably calling a different python interpreter from the command line. What platform are you on?  Is there a chance you have multiple interpreters installed? Try comparing the output of `import sys; print sys.executable` from the command line and from a file that you double-click to run..

Comment: Thanks Joe!! My HP Computer preinstalled a python interpreter at C:\hp\bin\python which I didn't aware of.

Comment: @Joe: That should've been an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: @Macke No, it's fine as a comment. He prompted OP for more information and gave a suggestion, not a factual answer. If the OP solved the problem with help of the suggestion, then OP should add an answer himself on what the solution was and accept it.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt4/PyQt-4.10.3/PyQt4-4.10.3-gpl-Py2.7-Qt4.8.5-x64.exe - install it Windows 7 64-bit

Answer (score 4):

PyQt installation also depends on the version of python installed on your platform.Python3.+ is incompatible with Python version < 3.x.

I was facing the same problem as I have Python 2.7 installed on my machine but I downloaded the latest binary which was PyQt-Py3.2-x86-gpl-4.9.exe. If you see here the binary has python version also mentioned in name after PyQt which is Py3.2. I uninstalled PyQt and installed PyQt-Py2.7-x86-gpl-4.9.exe which points to Python 2.7 and it fixed the problem.

Probably they could have mentioned the naming convention online or in some documentation to be more simpler.

Comment: I've got the same problem. I downloaded PyQt5-5.2.1-gpl-Py3.3-Qt5.2.1-x64 but it didn't work with Python 2.7. I couldn't find an appropriate PyQt5 installer for Python 2. Is there one? Do I need to build from source? Or do I need to use PyQt4 instead? PyQt5 is supposed to be compatible with Python 2.6+.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Windows, you'd need to find the python installation directory and add it to the PATH.

Append the following line to your existing path (be sure to replace "Path\To\Python" with the correct Path) and yes, the semicolon is required.

```
;C:\Path\To\Python
```

Comment: Thanks SeeJay. I solved the problem by removing the duplicated python interpreter from the PATH

Answer (score 0):

```
"""
0) Windows 7 - 64-bit installed 

1) install python 2.7.3 (64-bit)

  http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.3/python-2.7.3.amd64.msi

2) install pyqt4: 

  http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt4/PyQt-4.10.3/PyQt4-4.10.3-gpl-Py2.7-Qt4.8.5-x64.exe

"""

# Play!
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
widget = QWidget()
widget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]